# LEAD function syntax in HIVE-QL

Tags: sql, hadoop, hive, bigdata, hiveql

Is there any way to convert below LEAD function into HIVE QL format??

```
NVL(LEAD(START_DT) OVER (PARTITION BY EV_ID,AR_EV_RLTNSHP_TYPE_CD ORDER BY START_DT)-1,'2099-12-31') AS DERIVED_END_DT
```

**PFB the error:**

> FAILED: ParseException line 1:1599 missing ) at 'OVER' near '(' in
>   subquery source line 1:1603 missing FROM at '(' near '(' in subquery
>   source line 1:1604 cannot recognize input near 'PARTITION' 'BY'
>   'EV_ID' in subquery source

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is complicated in HiveSQL but you can do it with a `left join` and aggregation:

```
select t.ev_id, t.ar_ev_rltnshp_type_cd, t.start_date,
       coalesce(min(tnext.start_dt) - 1, '2099-12-31') as derived_end_dt
from table t left join
     table tnext
     on t.ev_id = tnext.ev_id and t.ar_ev_rltnshp_type_cd = tnext.ar_ev_rltnshp_type_cd and
        tnext.start_date > t.start_date
group by t.ev_id, t.ar_ev_rltnshp_type_cd, t.start_date;
```

This makes certain assumptions about `start_date` being unique within a given group, but it will probably work for your purposes.